# css display:block property error or behaving differently

Tags: javascript, html, css, nav

I want to make Responsive Navbar using flexbox and block (in small screen devices). Here I am applying display:flex to navbar_items in larger screens to show them in single line. However I want to display navbar_items as block elements in mobile view but inside my media query, I have selected navbar_items and menu_active but its not displaying me as flex. Its still showing me as flex.  I hope it makes sense to you, if its unclear please comments below or edit question for other people in understandable way.

```css
.navbar {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  background: black;
}

.navbar_logo a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
}

.navbar_item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav_link {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

.nav_link a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media(max-width:798px) {
  .navbar {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar_item .menu_active {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar_logo">
    <a href="./index.html">Inspire 2020</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="navbar_item menu_active">
    <li class="nav_link"><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav_link"><a href="#">Events</a></li>
    <li class="nav_link"><a href="#">Schedule</a></li>
    <li class="nav_link"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the .menu_active from .navbar_item no need to select it.

```
 @media(max-width:798px)
    {
      .navbar li
      {
        display: block;
        color: blue;
      }
      .navbar_item
      {
        display: block ;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I want to make it display block when nabvar_item has menu_active class. If it does not have menu_active class then I have to make it display none because then navbar is not open. I want to make Navbar visible if and only if navbar_item has menu_active class.

Comment: is this what you want https://codepen.io/bungarazvan/pen/vYEpgxo ??